# Assign an object to 'data' property in '$.ajax' method of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object

This is what I know on the subject:

We have an ajax function to which we can pass an object with properties like this:

```
    var ajaxRequest = {};

    ajaxRequest['type'] = 'POST';
    ajaxRequest['async'] = false;
    ajaxRequest['datatype'] = 'json';
    ajaxRequest['url'] = '/Query/getMydata';

    $.ajax(ajaxRequest);
```

one of these properties is the data parameter which is made of key / value pairs:

```
    ajaxRequest['data'] = {color: 'red' , name: 'Steve' }
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
    var oData = [];
    oData['color'] = 'yellow';
    oData['name'] = 'Fred';

    ajaxRequest['data'] = oData;
```

but it does not work.

So my question is: there is an object that I can assign to the  'data' parameter, or I am forced to build the string with concatenation?

EDIT==============

Maybe I did not explain, I know that the method can be created by code like this:

```
     var ajaxRequest = {
      type: 'POST',
      async: false
      ....
      };
```

but I'm using objects and properties because I need to make the method 'generic', then I will add the 'if' like this:

```
    function ajaxReq(data){
         var ajaxRequest = {};

         if( !data.isEmpty()){
             ajaxRequest['data'] = data;
         }

           ajaxRequest['type'] = 'POST';
           ajaxRequest['async'] = false;
           ajaxRequest['datatype'] = 'json';
           ajaxRequest['url'] = '/Query/getMydata';

           ...

           $.ajax(ajaxRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Don´t make it a string; `ajaxRequest['data'] = {color: 'red' , name: 'Steve' };`

Comment: I had wrong writing, sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your complex method is entirely unnecessary. You should just be using object literals:

```
var ajaxRequest = {
    type: 'POST',
    async: false
    datatype: 'json',
    url: '/Query/getMydata'
};

$.ajax(ajaxRequest);
```

You can also nest them, so you could have this:

```
var ajaxRequest = {
    type: 'POST',
    async: false
    datatype: 'json',
    url: '/Query/getMydata',
    data: {
        color: 'yellow',
        name: 'Fred'
    }
};
```

jQuery will convert this into a query string for you, so you don't need to worry about that.

---

An additional clarification... The reason that `oData = []` is causing problems is that `[]` creates an array. In Javascript, arrays are a special kind of object. Only properties with numeric keys are considered members of the array (e.g. `oData[1]`). If you'd used an object literal (`{}`) as you did with `ajaxRequest`, it would have worked fine.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clear what I wanted to do. And I knew what you wrote in the first part of your answer. I had not noticed that I created an array instead of an object Litteral, and the second part of your answer solved my poblem! Thank you!

Comment: @benVG Fair enough, but it would make sense to construct as many elements as possible within the object literal, i.e. those that are constant. Note also that you can do `ajaxRequest.url = '/Query/getMydata'`, for instance, to save characters and neaten code.

Comment: I did not know this,it will certainly help me!